# What caused a massive traffic spike around April the 8th

Tags: discussion, statistics

I noticed that page views of the site started going up on the 5th of April and peaked at 13 times normal before going back to normal on the 12th.

Does anyone know what caused this?

I am unaware of any recent groundbreaking new proofs.

Comment: What specifically did you see? Where did you check this?

Comment: I am not sure I'm allowed to post exact numbers. It's in the site analytics.

Comment: @RudytheReindeer You're not explicitly forbidden, per se: "Since this is a restricted privilege, we'd prefer you not share the raw data. However, we do hope you will share your analysis of the data with other users on meta." https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a technical issue of the measurement not a  genuine increase.

See for example [Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51)